# Prevent XML attribute reordering during APK build

Tags: xml, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

> Edit: Please don't spend time educating me that relying on attribute
> order is broken. I know! I agree! But I don't own the application that's doing
> it (Apex Launcher), and millions of users have it installed, so please help me find a
> solution that's under **my** control.

I have an XML file with attributes set in a **particular order** in my Android project (why?[1]). Unfortunately, when I build this project, then the resulting APK and Bundle contain the file with its attributes reordered alphabetically. There are actually two questions:

- Which component in my toolchain is performing that sort? Gradle? Android Studio? Something else? (See my toolchain plus versions in [2])
- How can I prevent this alphabetical sorting?

The original file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shader version="1.0">
    <exec t="OA" m="W" v="IA"/>
</shader>
```

The resulting file in the APK; note how `t` and `m` were reordered:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shader version="1.0">
    <exec m="W" t="OA" v="IA"/>
</shader>
```

I feel like I know too little to ask the question properly, so if any crucial information is missing, please ask. Setting `minifyEnabled` to `false` in the Gradle build script did not help and is the only meaningful thing I tried so far.

[1] Why: There's an application that's reading the XML file from my Android app and it's relying on the original attribute order or won't work otherwise. Dumb, I know, and they haven't fixed this in over a year, so I'm looking for workarounds.

[2] Toolchain / Versions:

- Android Studio: Flamingo | 2022.2.1 Patch 1
- Gradle Version: 8.0
- Compile SDK: 33

Comment: XML attributes order is irrelevant. No need to worry about it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, @YitzhakKhabinsky but in my case it does matter, see the "why" statement at the end of my question.

Answer (score 0):

The thing that's broken in your toolchain is the application that expects attributes to be in a particular order. That's the component that's broken, and that's the one you should fix.

As a workaround, you could write an application that reads an XML file and outputs the attributes in the correct order. Most low-level XML-writing tools will emit the attributes in the order you output them.

The Saxon serializer has an option saxon:attribute-order to control the order of attributes in the output; you could try that.

Try to confine your workaround to a single step in the pipeline that reorders the attributes immediately prior to the buggy step, which you can remove once the bug is fixed.

Comment: Is your answer specific to Android or just basic XML parser advice? I'm putting a file in the `res/xml` folder of my Android application, so I have no influence over any parsers used, and I also can't put files in there after the fact. (Edit: Also, I can't fix that other application which is reading the file, it's been doing it wrong for over a year and I need a solution. https://natewren.com/blank-icons-in-some-launchers/)

Comment: It's completely general advice applicable to android or anything else. In general you should assume that any XML tool will deliver attributes in unpredictable order. Some parsers will deliver attributes in a consistent order, but it's bad practice to rely on it.

Comment: No, sorry, your advice is not applicable to the Android build process. I put XML files into a specific folder, have it build the APK and there's no low-level XML-writing tool access whatsoever. Also, I made an effort to explain why I need this reordering: The app "Apex Launcher" has 10 million users and I have zero control over it. But I need it to pick up the XML from my app properly. See the link.